# SQL Select and Group By clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data as per the table below, I pass in a list of numbers and need the `raceId` where all the numbers appear in the the data column for that race.

```
+-----+--------+------+
| Id  | raceId | data |
+-----+--------+------+
|  14 |      1 |    1 |
|  12 |      1 |    2 |
|  13 |      1 |    3 |
|  16 |      1 |    8 |
|  47 |      2 |    1 |
|  43 |      2 |    2 |
|  46 |      2 |    6 |
|  40 |      2 |    7 |
|  42 |      2 |    8 |
|  68 |      3 |    3 |
|  69 |      3 |    6 |
|  65 |      3 |    7 |
|  90 |      4 |    1 |
|  89 |      4 |    2 |
|  95 |      4 |    6 |
|  92 |      4 |    7 |
|  93 |      4 |    8 |
| 114 |      5 |    1 |
| 116 |      5 |    2 |
| 117 |      5 |    3 |
| 118 |      5 |    8 |
| 138 |      6 |    2 |
| 139 |      6 |    6 |
| 140 |      6 |    7 |
| 137 |      6 |    8 |
+-----+--------+------+
```

Example I pass in `1,2,7` I would get the following Id's:

```
2 and 4
```

I have tried the simple statement

SELECT *  FROM table WHERE ((data = 1) or (data = 2) or (data = 7))

But I don't really understand the grouping by clause or indeed if it is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: What is your question? What have you already tried?

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: how you pass the list?

Comment: I pass the list as a comma separated string. '1,2,7' 

I have the written the code to split the string and then I intended to build up the query statement and run it within SQL Server.

That is unless I am going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select raceId
from yourtable
where data in (1,2,7)
group by raceId
having count(raceId) = 3 /* length(1,2,7) */
```

This is assuming raceId, data pair is unique. If it's not the you should use

```
select raceId
from (select distinct raceId, data
      from yourtable
      where data in(1,2,7))
group by raceId
having count(raceId) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT raceId WHERE data IN (1, 2, 7)
```

Comment: This is not going to provide the results that the OP requested. IN will return all raceIDs where data matches any of the items in the list, not ALL as indicated.

Comment: ahh - I missed that point - probably read the question too quickly and assumed any.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to solve these with `group by` and `having`.

```
select raceid
from races
where data in (1, 2, 7)
group by raceid
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon looks just like what I need. I don't really understand the having count bit - I assume that it relates the the number of 'numbers' within the in query?

Comment: @SteveH . . . It ensures that there are three matches.